# minha pergunta é sobre o erro: Uncaught ReferenceError: createSlider is not defined

Tags: javascript, html

estou fazendo um jogo no estilo do "flappy bird" porém estou tendo um problema com o Slider,creio que seja algo com biblioteca ou a própria forma como declarei a variável ou o createSlider mas já tentei mudar e nada resolve 
o projeto não é original meu ele vem do canal "the codding train,Coding Challenge #41: Clappy Bird!" ele usa essa variável exatamente em [11:42 no video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aKiyCeIuwn4&list=PLVuaqyVQG_L3kGhI2ncOU2GIduZ4v97Du&t=689s&index=4) deixarei anexado o link e o codigo.

```
var bird; //variável passaro
var pipes = []; //variavel das paredes
var mic;
var slider;

function setup() {
   createCanvas(400, 600); //tamanho da janela 400x600
   mic = new p5.AudioIn(); //para chamar a biblioteca de microfone
   mic.start(); //para aparecer o pop up no navegador para aceitar a usar o    microfone
   bird = new Bird(); //para mostrar o passaro na tela
   pipes.push(new Pipe()); //para mostrar as paredes
   slider = createSlider(0, 1, 0.2, 0.01);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tens razão, falta incluíres uma dependência para teres a função `createSlider`.

No teu HTML tens de importar a libraria p5js, porque é essa que disponibiliza a função `createSlider`.

Podes ver o código completo criado por ele no [repositório do github](https://github.com/CodingTrain/website/tree/master/CodingChallenges/CC_041_ClappyBird_p5.js).

Comment: correto,muito obrigado de coração!!! eu tinha a biblioteca porém era mais atualizada e ocorria problema com ela.